# Tikz use custom label in enumeration causes line spacing to be too large

Tags: tikz-pgf, enumerate, tikz-styles, line-spacing

I want to use custom symbols in an enumeration using tikz. Currently, my code looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\zzzz[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,fill,yellow,inner sep=1pt] (char) {\textcolor{black}{#1}};}}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no.
\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\zzzz{$Z_\arabic*$}, leftmargin=*, noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
    \item \emph{Bla bla bla:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    \item \emph{Bla bla bla:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:
[image]

What I don't like about this is that the first line of each `\item` has a larger line spacing than the rest. I assume it's because the tikz circle (enumeration symbol) is too large to fit within a line. Is it possible to reduce the line spacing only for the first line to achieve consistency without needing to reduce the yellow circles in size?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this.

It tells the tikz nodes size to be ignored  (overlay), then make space for it in the design of the list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\zzzz[1]{
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base),overlay]{
    \node[shape=circle,fill,yellow,inner sep=1pt] (char) {\textcolor{black}{#1}};}}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no.
\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\zzzz{$Z_\arabic*$},noitemsep, topsep=0pt, labelwidth=1em,align=left]
    \item \emph{Bla bla bla:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    \item \emph{Bla bla bla:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing. Exactly how I wanted it to be. Thank you. Will mark the answer as accepted as soon as SE lets me to do so (timeout).